# Dynamically increase number (count elements)

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to put a number in a list of elements - a dynamically increasing number - like:

```
1. text
2. text
3. ...
...
```

So far I have this:

```
var c = {
    current: 0,
    count: function () {
        this.current++
    }
}
$('.box').each(function (index) {
    $(".number").text(c.current + 1);
    c.count();
});
```

- see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzk3P/3/). But what am I missing? how do I give each element its own number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Qzk3P/4/, you forgot to add context parameter, see example below:

```
$(".number", this).text(c.current + 1);
```

notice `this`

EDIT: I've added another example with css-property counter, you may also like it: http://jsfiddle.net/Qzk3P/6/

Comment: That's brilliant... Thanks, Pawel_W.

Comment: +1, an option: `$(this).find('.number').text(c.current + 1);`

Comment: I liked the css-property counter - very neat!

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the text of `".number"`, which happens to exist 4 times. Update your code like that:

```
$('.box').each(function (index) {
    $(".number", this).text(c.current + 1);
    c.count();
});
```

The `this` is the context. So you are only looking for the `".number"` element inside the currently iterating `".box"`

Answer (score 1):

Also you seem to be trying to do a little too much.

This is all that you need to do.

```
var count = 0;
$('.box').each(function (index) {
    count ++;
    $(".number", this).text(count);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qzk3P/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = {
    current: 0,
    count: function () {
        this.current++
    }
}
$('.box').each(function (index,v) {
    $(v).children(".number").text(++c.current);
    //c.count();
});
```